# Encounter TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object when doing model fitting for my siamese network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter

I'm trying to do the model fitting for a siamese network. Here is my generator:

```
def gen(list_tuples, person_to_images_map, batch_size=16):
  ppl = list(person_to_images_map.keys())
  while True:
    batch_tuples = sample(list_tuples, batch_size // 2)
    labels = [1] * len(batch_tuples)
    while len(batch_tuples) < batch_size:
        p1 = choice(ppl)
        p2 = choice(ppl)

        if p1 != p2 and (p1, p2) not in list_tuples and (p2, p1) not in list_tuples:
            batch_tuples.append((p1, p2))
            labels.append(0)

    for x in batch_tuples:
        if not len(person_to_images_map[x[0]]):
            print(x[0])

    X1 = [choice(person_to_images_map[x[0]]) for x in batch_tuples]
    X1 = np.array([read_img(x) for x in X1])

    X2 = [choice(person_to_images_map[x[1]]) for x in batch_tuples]
    X2 = np.array([read_img(x) for x in X2])

    yield [X1, X2], np.array(labels)
```

I fit the model using:

```
model.fit(gen(train, train_person_to_images_map, batch_size=16), use_multiprocessing=True,
                validation_data=gen(val, val_person_to_images_map, batch_size=16), epochs=100, verbose=1,
                workers=4, callbacks=callbacks_list, steps_per_epoch=200, validation_steps=100)
```

It gives my type error after two minutes but the jupyter notebook cell shows it's still running. I feed a size-10 data to it and it stuck in Epoch1/100 for two hours.

---

Epoch 1/100
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object

Should I keep waiting or is there any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score -1):

`use_multiprocessing=True` won't work with generator input if your generator takes unpickable arguments (e.g. other generators) as arguments.

You could either just set `use_multiprocessing=False` (at expense of some performance probably) or make sure that you don't have unpickable arguments (from the code you've provided it's hard to say what `list_tuples` and `person_to_images_map` are).

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit